# Is there a quick way to tell if an app is in Django's INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a quick Django module and want to check for another module. Is there's a shortcut to check if another module is in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in Django's settings?

Comment: You have the source for settings.  Why can't you read the `settings.py` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from settings import INSTALLED_APPS
if 'appname' in INSTALLED_APPS:
    print 'we have app'
```

And this way is somewhat [how Django itself does](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/loading.py?rev=10088#L55). Also check the `load_app` method on the linked page.

Comment: Link is now dead

Answer (score 7):

Django contains a [registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#application-registry) of installed applications that you can use for this purpose:

```
>>> from django.apps import apps
>>> apps.is_installed("django.contrib.admin")
True
```

Comment: I'll pick this answer. because INSTALLED_APPS should never be accessed directly. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#installed-apps